# Contact form 7 multi step wordpress The site is experiencing technical difficulties

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using contact form 7 multi step in wordpress and when I'm using this shortcode in my file I am getting this error. and when I am removing my shortcode with multistep, error isn't coming. Please help 
**The site is experiencing technical difficulties**
here's my shortocde 
`[multistep "1-3-https://mywebsite.com/driver-form-2"]`

**Here is my Debug Error**

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WPCF7_FormTag' not found in /home/website.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7-multi-step-module/form-tags/module-multistep.php:58 Stack trace: #0 /home/website.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/shortcodes.php(174): cf7msm_multistep_shortcode_handler(Array) #1 [internal function]: WPCF7_ShortcodeManager->do_shortcode_tag(Array) #2 /home/website.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/shortcodes.php(94): preg_replace_callback('/(\\[?)\\[(respon...', Array, '<div style="hei...') #3 /home/website.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/contact-form.php(500): WPCF7_ShortcodeManager->do_shortcode('<div style="hei...') #4 /home/website.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/contact-form.php(559): WPCF7_ContactForm->form_do_shortcode() #5 /home/website.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/contact-form.php(342): WPCF7_ContactForm->form_elements() #6 /home/naxtelca/rideonri in /home/website.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7-multi-step-module/form-tags/module-multistep.php on line 58`

Comment: what does `debug.log` say?

Comment: updated the answer. please check the debug error

Comment: Try updating the contact-form-7-multi-step-module, if it does not help also try an older version of that plugin.